# Obtaining certain value from child table

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables:
Customer (Parent)
Agreement (Child)

I need to display a certain value in my query if one of the many agreement statusID's has a certain value (e.g. written off).  The join between the two tables is CustomerID.

So if a customer has 3 agreements and 2 agreements have a statusID of 1 and one has 5, I need to display a certain value.  I only want to return one row in this query rather than the 3 which would occur in a typical join

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want specifically when there are 2 agreements with statid = 1 and one with 5 to do your things? or its just an example?

Comment: Thanos, I've looked at using FOR XML to bring all the values in one string within a CTE, but given data volumes I am concerned about performance

Comment: Sagi, that was just an example, there are 4 different scenarios I need to code for.  If all = 1, the return 1. If one = 5 then return 5.  If all = 1 or 2 then return 1.  Else return statusID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    CustomerID,
    max(case when StatusId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as HasStatus1,
    max(case when StatusId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as HasStatus2
    --etc.
from Customer
left join Agreement
group by Customer.CustomerID
```

This will return a single row per customer due to the group by, with flags indicating if they have any agreements in each status of concern - if you're looking this up for a single `CustomerID` you'd obviously throw a where statement in there, and you could remove the group by as well (you'd have to remove `CustomerID` from the result set though of course).

Taking into account your comment, you'd want something like:

```
;with grouped as (
    select
        CustomerID,
        max(case when StatusId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as HasStatus1,
        max(case when StatusId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as HasStatus2,
        max(case when StatusId = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as HasStatus5
        --etc.
    from Customer
    left join Agreement
    group by Customer.CustomerID
)
select
    CustomerID,
    case
        when HasStatus5 = 1 then 5
        when (HasStatus1 = 1 OR HasStatus2) and <no other status>) then 1
        --etc.
        else <Can't return StatusId here because there might be more than one... so whatever your default actually is> END as Result
from grouped
```